# Delete node from firease instantly after network disconnection

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one angular application where I am storing users online / offline status in firebase. How to delete data of user from firebase immediately after internet goes off.
currently i used following code snippet in my angular project:

```
const db = getDatabase();
const connectedRef = ref(db, '.info/connected');

var myPresenceRef = this.angularFireDatabase.database.ref(
  '/presence/' + this.userInfo['username']
);

onValue(connectedRef, (snap) => {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    console.log('connected to db');}
  else {
     myPresenceRef.onDisconnect().remove();
  }
```

I want to delete data immediately. how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force the deletion to happen immediately after the connection is closed.

- At that point the client can't force a delete anymore, because it is no longer connected to the server.
- And the server will only execute the `onDisconnect()` handler once it detects that the client is gone.

  - This may happen right away - in the case of a clean disconnect, where the SDL announces to the server that it'll be disconnecting.
  - Or this may take a few minutes - in the case of a dirty disconnect when the connection is closed in some other way. This is not some implementation detail or choice, but just the nature of how internet connections work.

This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though, so rather than how you think it should be implemented, it'd be good to think about **what** you're trying to accomplish and then how you can map that to capabilities of the product(s) you're using.